# Flag window moves around, annoyingly

Tags: bug, status-completed, flag-dialog

Tested on Stack Overflow and on Chemistry

When you're trying to flag something and move your flag window out of the way (if for example you want to read through it again just to double check) it will move around the screen if you select certain options.

Observe

[image: It moves from the side to the center upon clicking "It should be closed for other reasons" and then back when clicking "flagging"]

This is pretty annoying.

I'm on Chrome 37.0.2062.120

Comment: TIL you can actually move the flag window

Comment: It's because the flag dialog reloads when you select a new option. I'm pretty sure that's [meta-tag:status-bydesign] unless you want to make this a [meta-tag:feature-request] for SE to keep track of where your flag dialog is every time you load it.

Comment: It doesn't even reload, it hides the original and shows a new modal, which has its own (original) absolute positioning.

Comment: @StephanMuller maybe it should import the previous one ;)

Comment: Out of curiosity, what did you use to make the gif?

Comment: @AstroCB: The way you describe it sounds more like status-byimplementationdetail rather than by design.

Comment: @Blackhawk ffmpeg?

Comment: @Blackhawk I used [LICEcap](http://www.cockos.com/licecap/), which I actually had as a comment but it appears it was deleted

Comment: @MarkPeters Unfortunately, SE employees often treat those as the same thing on these bug reports.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I observed. It was pretty annoying. I fixed it up. You'll see it working as you'd hope in the next PROD build (meta: > `rev 2014.9.24.2604`, q&a: > `rev 2014.9.24.1891`).